# knockout binding based on a dot-seperated string

Tags: knockout.js

I'm attempting to create HTML tables using knockout.js templates where the names of the properties to bind to are very dynamic and are returned from the server as JSON.

The JSON is in a format like:

```
{"Columns": [
     {"Title": "First Name", "Bind": "Person.FirstName"},
     {"Title": "Last Name", "Bind": "Person.LastName"},
     {"Title": "Birth Date", "Bind": "Person.DOB"}
  ],
  "Rows": [
     {
        "Person": {
           "FirstName": "James",
           "LastName": "Jameson",
           "DOB": "5/7/1965"
        },
        "Person": {
           "FirstName": "Bob",
           "LastName": "Bobson",
           "DOB": "12/15/1976"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

Given this JSON, I would like to create a template that generates the following HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Birth Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>James</td>
      <td>Jameson</td>
      <td>5/7/1965</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>Bobson</td>
      <td>12/15/1976</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

I know how to do this using a custom html binding that calls into a javascript function or by creating the HTML on the server and applying bindings to it, but I'd much rather use templates if possible.

I understand that this is an odd use of knockout, but the JSON comes from the server and its format can be changed at runtime.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This may fit your bill: https://github.com/mbest/knockout-table

Answer (score 0):

Knockout as other MVVM implementations allows you to use templates with specific markup in them that let's knockout know where to insert the data.

We use Kendo MVVM which is similiar. We load the template into our view using an ajax call to retrieve the template html and bind the template to the view model. We do not use script tags at all.

Here is an article that explains how to do this with Knockout

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html